# What are names of the animations used in this carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate, css-animations

Link of the carousel https://www.unhcr.org/fr-fr/monpaysestuncamp/

i'm trying to make the same carousel by myself.can somebody tell me the names of the animations which the carousel using..

i know the name of the one animation which is "zoomin".
i need to know the animation name of the other which goes from the left to right.

Comment: this is more a carousel than slider

Comment: @brk can you please tell me the animation name then ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check this out:

[Codepen by toddwebdev](http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://codepen.io/toddwebdev/pen/yExKoj&ved=2ahUKEwjVodWincjkAhVBPFAKHWgvA34QFjAAegQIABAB)

Does quite the same as on the website you showed.